# Magento 1.9 Add new fields in registration form?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, registration

I want to 3 additional fields in customer registration form (only for my Brasilian shop) and store these in the user data in the backend.

Comment: Did you created those 3 customer attributes in admin? Also update your register.phtml for brasilian shop?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: What are the attributes you want?

Comment: Nome Fantasia,Inscrição Estadual,Nº

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332434/adding-additional-field-to-registration-form-in-magento-1-9